# Can't make .jar file executable on xfce4

Tags: command-line, xfce, minecraft

I am new to XFCE and I am trying to get minecraft.jar to run, but I can't because it says I need to make it into an executable file (since XFCE deals with executables strangely, for security reasons i suppose) so I right-clicked the file and went into properties. When I went over to the properties tab, I couldn't find a checkbox to make it executable. Next, I tried to use terminal to make it executable using the chmod a+x minecraft.jar command, but it says that there is no such file with that name. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to run the command in the same folder the file is in, otherwise you'll get that obvious error message.

Answer (score 1):

To make it executable, you need to specify your `.jar` files location:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/file.jar
```

Otherwise, you can also directly make it executable by right clicking the `.jar` file, go to the **Permissions** tab and check the **Execute** option.

Another ways to go is run the `.jar` files from terminal using `java -jar` command, as @Sadaharu pointed out:

```
java -jar /path/to/file.jar
```

Without having messing with executable thing, this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

First move file into your home folder.

change it executable with full path

```
chmod a+x ~/minecraft.jar
```

This should work now, execute in background add &

```
java -jar ~/minecraft.jar
```

Comment: `/home` isn't the user's home folder, and you don't need to set it executable to run it with `java -jar`.

Comment: Wow, sorry I was a half asleep!